# Check of the first text node is a number

Tags: jquery, textnode

I want to check to see if the first node of a div is number and if it's null I'll display a div or not.

http://jsfiddle.net/NsXsa/

```
            $(".carcount").bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){

    $(function() {
        $(".carcount span").filter(function() {
            var carnumber = get(0).firstChild.data; 

            if ($.isNumeric(carnumber)) {
                $('.carcount').css({ 'display': 'none' });
                    }                   

            else {
                $('.carcount').css({ 'display': 'block' });
                }                       
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

`$.isNumeric(carnumber )`

It's a built in function in jquery.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/

Comment: `$(".carcount").bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
    $(function() {
      if([0].firstChild.data.isNumeric($('.carcount').val())) {
         $('.carcount').css({ 'display': 'none' });
                    }                   
           else {
                $('.carcount').css({ 'display': 'inline' });
                }                       
        });
    });`

Like this?

Answer (score 0):

Check console and see whats the value of carnumber using `console.log(carnumber)`

You might also have to use `parseInt()` to convert string to number.

```
 $(".carcount").bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
    $(function() {
        $(".carcount").filter(function() {
            var carnumber = parseInt(get(0).firstChild.data, 10); 
            if ( carnumber < 2 ) {
                $('.extra-zero').css({ 'display': 'none' });
                    }                   
            else {
                $('.extra-zero').css({ 'display': 'inline' });
                }                       
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I dont' want to convert string to a number. I just want to see if the first text is a number or not

Comment: Did you try to print the value of carnumber in console?

Comment: You can use isNaN(carnumber) to find if carnumber is not a number

Comment: If you don't convert string to number, the the comparison carnumber < 2 might not work properly